# Pydoop job not running

Tags: java, python, hadoop

I have setup a single-node Hadoop 1.2.1 cluster and trying to run this script:

```
pydoop script transpose.py matrix.txt t_matrix
```

The script returns nothing and the job is in pending status.

The question is, after running the script the job is in pending status for more than 10 minutes. Why the Job is not running properly?

And this is the output generated while running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/hduser/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local   
/taskTracker/distcache/-2030848362897089950_-2130723868_1886929692/localhost 
/user/hduser /pydoop_script_91c491cf7e6b42f6bcbeda09edae9385  
/exe90d967507f86405a9606c35582b2fc43", line 10, in import pydoop.pipes File"/usr/local 
/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydoop/pipes.py", line 29, in pp =    
pydoop.import_version_specific_module('_pipes') File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-  
packages/pydoop/__init__.py", line 107, in import_version_specific_module return  
import_module(complete_mod_name(name)) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importli/__init__.py",  
line 37, in import_module __import__(name) ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/pydoop/_pipes_1_2_1.so: undefined symbol: BIO_s_mem
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: @Arvinth: Kindly check the logs in jobtracker web url, if that possible.

Comment: @ashiaka The question is After running the script the Job is in pending status for more than 10 minutes transpose.py Why the Job is not running properly?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker                                           java.lang.Throwable: Child Error at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1. at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258

Comment: MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201312081130_0001_m_000001" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201312081130_0001_m_000001_0" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1386487003163" HOSTNAME="aravinth" ERROR="Task attempt_201312081130_0001_m_000001_0 failed to report status for 600 seconds\. Killing!" logs in the t_matrix file

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker help me.Is now my question understandble

Comment: @Aravinth, at this point I can only suggest you to know how to do the setup of pydoop properly in every node and then look for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one required SSL library.
You will need to find and link "libssl.so.1.0.0" in your environment.
Try to execute the following before running your pydoop script:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=PATH_TO/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

For example:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```